# CakePHP 1.3: ACL Issue with plugins

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, acl

ACL seems to be very confusing and never problem-free. Although, I've had no major problems using ACL, everytime I add a plugin I run into issue. I've looked at the ACO table in the Db, but to no avail.

I downloaded McCurry Cakephp's plugin STATUS. However, when I access it, I get the following error:

```
DbAcl::check() - Failed ACO node lookup in permissions check.
```

I am using Alaxos ACL plugin. When I run it, it looks like it detected the new plugin and added the correct ACOs. If I rerun it, I get a message saying there is no new ACOs to add.

The issue if coming from the following section in the CakePHP's core ACL Component

```
function check($aro, $aco, $action = "*") {
    if ($aro == null || $aco == null) {
        return false;
    }

            ....

    $acoPath = $this->Aco->node($aco);

            ...

    // The issue is happening here!!! Basically $acoPath has '' from the call above
    if ($acoPath == null || $acoPath == array() || empty($acoPath)) {
                  trigger_error(__("DbAcl::check() - Failed ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:\nAro: ", true) . print_r($aro, true) . "\nAco: " . print_r($aco, true), E_USER_WARNING);
                return false;
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: If you aren't already - I would consider using the acl_extras plugin. It will give you a variety of tools to rebuild your ACL/ACO/ARO tree.

Comment: Barry, I could not find a CakePHP 1.3 version. The one in GitHub is for 2.0. Can you guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit this link and click download as zip or tarball.

`https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/zipball/1.0.0`